# how to save the content of html form as .html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying creating an online drag and drop form and would like to know how to save the dropped contents along with their respective id's with HTML extension or as a template.
HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="divcontainer">
        //in div1 and div3 m dropping the fields randomly
        <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event,this.id)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
        <div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event,this.id)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

after dropping all the fields, i want to save the form as an HTML page. Can anyone suggest me how to do so.

Comment: Can you please whip a jFiddle on this?  It'll help and you would get more feedbacks awful easy this way.  http://jsfiddle.net/ and once you get it ran, then copy and paste the url in your question.

Comment: the link http://jsfiddle.net/UhJfn/ shows an alert message which captures the content of the page..i want to save the content as an html page..

Comment: Oh I didn't realize you were actually looking for something that I have already created.  This is called faron-formstrap.  Check it out.  It does everything what you want to see.

http://www.faronintel.ca/formstrap and github for this is at https://github.com/faroncoder/faron-formstrap

Comment: i used the code from the link http://jsfiddle.net/UhJfn/ to get the content from the page..now the problem what i'm facing is writing into an html file..while using 'alert' i m able to see the entire code which includes all the contents but when its written into the html, few tags gets skipped..specially the ending tags of 'div' and 'form'

Comment: Code goes like this :$("input#getform").click(function(){
         var saveForm = '<form>'+$('#divcontainer').html()+'</form>';
          alert(saveForm);
/*         save_content_to_file(saveForm, "test");*/
    
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open('GET', "write.php?content="+saveForm, false);
            request.send();
            if (request.status === 200) {
            /*alert(request.responseText);*/
            //document.getElementById('infodivsub').innerHTML=request.responseText;
            }
         
         
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the html inside divcontainer

like

```
$('#divcontainer').html()
```

or

```
document.getElementById('divcontainer').innerHTML
```

Then you should append this content to form tag like

```
var saveForm = '<form>'+$('#divcontainer').html()+'</form>';
```

Now saveForm will have html for the form. You have save this as a page with wrapping html and body tags and you need back end technology like php or .net to save file.

Comment: i will be using php as backend

Comment: how to save the page with wrapping html when using php as backend?? can u help me out with this as well Bala!!

Comment: what you can do is. Pass this saveform variable to php function on page submit or through ajax where you get this content and write it to html file.