# Save html form as html file with submitted values

Tags: javascript, html, forms

First I'd like to say I read the answers to similar questions including this [how to save the content of html form as .html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21726294/how-to-save-the-content-of-html-form-as-html-page) but that did not solve my problem.

I'm building a reporting system that allows users to use templates to create reports. These templates are html forms and can be developed my any external application or manually. What my application does is, it imports these templates and presents them to the user when he is creating his reports and I want to save the submitted report as as an html file with all the values the user selected, be it text fields or checkboxes.

The above answer suggests using $('#myForm').html(). What this does is get the html of the form but does not include any values entered by the user. How can I achieve this?

**Update**

I'd like to say this templates are developed by an external application and could have any structure depending on what the user is reporting. So I don't know of any id or name attribute of any of the form inputs used by the creator of the form. The only think I know of is that all the forms are always in a

```
<div id="reportTemplate"></div>
```

so that's the only thing I can access with javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [innerHTML with current form values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826222/innerhtml-with-current-form-values)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the html content in a variable and export it using anchor tag like below.

```js
function CreateHtml() {
  var htmlContent = "";
  htmlContent = "<h1>Name - " + $('#name').val() + "</h1><br>" +
    "<p>Email - " + $('#email').val() + "</p>";

  $('#btn_download').attr('download', 'sampleFile.html');
  $('#btn_download').attr('href', 'data:text/html,' + htmlContent);
  $('#btn_download').show();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input placeholder="Name" id="name" type="text" />
  <br/>
  <input placeholder="Email" id="email" type="text" />
  <br/>
  <button type="button" onclick="CreateHtml();">Submit</button>
  <br>
  <a href="" id="btn_download" hidden>Download</a>
</div>
```

Updated:

```js
function CreateHtml() {
  var htmlContent = TraverseThroughReport();

  $('#btn_download').attr('download', 'sampleFile.html');
  $('#btn_download').attr('href', 'data:text/html,' + htmlContent);
  $('#btn_download').show();

}

function TraverseThroughReport() {
  var elements = document.getElementById("report").elements;
  var htmlContent = "";
  for (var i = 0, element; element = elements[i++];) {
    if (element.type === "text")
      //console.log("it's an empty textfield")
      htmlContent = "<h1>" + element.value + "</h1>";
  }
  //You can add as many conditions for placeholder etc to detect the form element type

  return htmlContent;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="report">
  <input placeholder="Name" id="name" type="text" />
  <br/>
  <input placeholder="Email" id="email" type="text" />
  <br/>
  <button type="button" onclick="CreateHtml();">Submit</button>
  <br>
  <a href="" id="btn_download" hidden>Download</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't use this. I said these templates are developed by an external application so I have no clue of the IDs of any element in the forms.

Comment: Is the form inside some particular tag always? Like <form> tag or something similar?

Comment: Yes. <div id="report"></div>

Comment: Then you could simply traverse all input type elements inside the "report" div and dynamically bind it to a variable. Rest of the process should be same. I have updated the answer if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript

```
function CreateHtml(){
 var field1 = $("#field1").val();
 var field2 = $("#field2").val();
 var fieldn = $("#fieldn").val();

 var form  = $("#myForm").clone();
 $(form).find("#field1").val(field1);
 $(form).find("#field2").val(field2);
 $(form).find("#fieldn").val(fieldn);

 $('#btn_download').attr('download', 'sampleFile.html');
 $('#btn_download').attr('href', 'data:text/html,' + form);
 $('#btn_download').show();
}
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input placeholder="field1" id="field1" type="text" />
  <br/>
  <input placeholder="field2" id="field2" type="text" />
  <br/>
  <button type="button" onclick="CreateHtml();">Submit</button>
  <br>
  <a href="" id="btn_download" hidden>Download</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't use this for the same reasons I commented on the other answer. See the update to the question. The forms are created externally and could have any structure depending on what the user is reporting so I don't know of any id or name attributes in these forms. The only thing I'm aware of is that these forms are always in a <div id="reportTemplate"></div>

Answer (score 0):

If I had asked my question properly or searched for existing questions using "innerHtml with form values" instead of "how to save html for as files" I would have been taken to this link [jquery get all form elements: input, textarea & select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862601/jquery-get-all-form-elements-input-textarea-select) with already good answers of which this particular one worked for me

```
$('input:text, input:hidden, input:password').each(function() {
  var v=this.value; 
  $(this).attr("magicmagic_value",v).removeAttr("value").val(v);
});
$('input:checkbox,input:radio').each(function() {
  var v=this.checked; 
  if(v) $(this).attr("magicmagic_checked","checked"); 
  $(this).removeAttr("checked"); 
  if(v) this.checked=true; 
});
$('select option').each(function() { 
  var v=this.selected; 
  if(v) $(this).attr("magicmagic_selected","selected"); 
  $(this).removeAttr("selected");
  if(v) this.selected=true; 
});
$('textarea').each(function() { 
  $(this).html(this.value); 
});

var magic=$('form').html().replace(/magicmagic_/g,"");

$('[magicmagic_value]').removeAttr('magicmagic_value');
$('[magicmagic_checked]').attr("checked","checked").
  removeAttr('magicmagic_checked');
$('[magicmagic_selected]').attr("selected","selected").
removeAttr('magicmagic_selected');
alert(magic);
```